# Why Ajax is not able to send array data?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Trying to send form data to a PHP page, **all parameters are sending successfully except `data:imagesBase64`**

this imagesBase64 is an array which I am trying to send, a few hours ago everything was fine but now it is not working I really don't know why.

All values are Posting successfully only this value is not posting also I am not able to see error in console because it redirected to URL where I am posting the data

```
 var imagesBase64 = ['abcdfd','dhydsu333ud','djhbsd'];


  $(function () {
    var frm = $("#saveform");
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
      $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr("method"),
        url: frm.attr("action"),
        data: {
          data: imagesBase64,
          PubId: $("#Publications").val(),
          sdate: $("#datepicker").val(), 
          pnumber: $("#pnumber").val()
        },
        cache: false,
        error: function (err, data) {
          console.log("There was an error. Try again please!" + data, err);
        },
        success: function (data) {
          alert("New message received");
        },
      });
      ev.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

**In PHP page -**

```
print_r($_POST['data']);
```

it gives an error undefined data, though when I tried with postman everything is working fine.

Comment: And if you try to convert your array in Json...? With stringify...?

Comment: @Juan — The question doesn't mention JSON.  jQuery will convert the array to `data[]=abcdfd&data[]=dhydsu333ud&data[]=djhbsd` automatically and PHP will interpret it as an array.

Comment: Always move preventDefault up to be the first statement. If any statements down the script gives ANY error, the form will submit

Comment: Check the `Preserve log` checkbutton in the console settings

Comment: @RiggsFolly I already said it was wroking was before, also It is not sending any paramters in `data: ?` whatever I am defining even string and int or array nothing post through ajax but rest data is posting successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> also I am not able to see error in console because it redirected to URL where I am posting the data

That's the problem.

You are submitting data to the server using a regular form submission and not with Ajax. Since your Ajax code isn't used, the data added in from outside the form isn't included.

This is *usually* caused by the regular form submission interrupting the Ajax request, but since you have `ev.preventDefault();` that shouldn't be the case here.

Possible reasons that might apply are:

- `var frm = $("#saveform")` fails to find the form because the selector is wrong or the form is added after the document is loaded with other JS
- You don't have jQuery loaded so the call to `$` fails
- You have jQuery Slim loaded which doesn't include an `ajax` method (moving the call to `preventDefault` so it is before the call to `ajax` would help catch this).

Your browser's developer tools should have an called something like "Persist Logs" which will prevent it from clearing the console when you navigate to a new page. Turn it on to aid your debugging. Here's what it looks like in Firefox:

[image: The cog menu in Firefox's developer tools]

Comment: Always move preventDefault up to be the first statement. If any statements down the script gives ANY error, the form will submit

Comment: if I tried to send any string or anything in ``data:"abc" that too is not posting rest is going fine.

Comment: @jeane — I don't understand what part of my answer gave you the idea that the cause of the problem was that the value of `data` was an array (or, in fact, anything to do with the value of `data` at all)

Comment: thanks @Quentin [error](https://imgur.com/a/4SPcriL) this error in console